# Rails enable before_action only on development env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 app I've got custom two_factor_authentication. Now I want to enable this 2fa only in development and test environment.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :check_two_factor_authentication, except: :check_authentication

  private

  def check_two_factor_authentication
    return true unless session[:challenge_id]

    redirect_to two_factor_path
  end
```

I've no idea what is `check_authentication` because inside entire app there is no such method - it comes from Devise gem I guess.

How to set that before action only to development environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried

```
if %w(development test).include?(Rails.env)
  before_action :check_two_factor_authentication, except: :check_authentication 
end
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Rails.env.development?` (or `Rails.env.production?`) to test which environment you are in.

```rb
if Rails.env.development?
  before_action :check_two_factor_authentication, except: :check_authentication
end
```